# Xamarin.Forms - Choose list

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I don't know what is the real name of what I want to do, but I would like to make a list similar as this **[website link](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#standard-select) (Standard Select part at the top)**, does anyone can help me? I know it's something easy but I can't find what I want to do it for Xamarin. Maybe I don't search  in the right direction, I assume it too!

Answer (score 1):

There's no 1-1 implementation of a dropdown control in Xamarin.Forms but you'll get very close by using the [Picker](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/) control.

Please notice that the default Picker control doesn't support binding so you might want to look for an [extended version with that support](https://oceanware.wordpress.com/2016/06/13/xamarin-forms-bindable-picker/).

Comment: Thank for your answer, I'll go eat and then work on it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing built in Xamarin.Forms. You can choose one of the controls described in [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/).

To implement what you are looking for you will have to use [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) with control like [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) from Android. Of course for iOS you will have to use something different because there is no such control on iOS platform, but you can use [this](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/CustomPicker).

Comment: Thank for your answer, I'll go eat and then work on it :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Syncfusion AutoComplete](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/autocomplete) control?

[image]I think this is the closest you will get to what you are looking for.

They also provide a free community licence for developers

Comment: Actually, I was looking for Picker, I mean, it was the solution. However, your answer is answering another question, so thank you ^^